# can no longer enable Feb breaking changes (only April) sO I cannot "fix" the alert. Any ideas on how to make the alert go away?

Tags: alert, facebook-apps

can no longer enable Feb breaking changes (only April) in advanced options of the application settings.  So I cannot "fix" the alert.  Any ideas on how to make the alert go away?